# In-App Purchases work when tested but do not work in review

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I've created my first app with a non-consumable in-app purchase and submitted it for review.

I tested the purchase on my device and it works fine but the review says they can't do this in-app purchase. It seems like the SKProducts they returned are 0 or the identifier was a different one.

I added the purchase to AppStoreConnect and added a synced .storekit file to my project. The purchase status is 'Ready to Submit' and has been added to the app in AppStoreConnect, then I submit it for review.

Am I missing something?

Is there any way to test it under similar conditions as the review?